# Linear distribution of numbers in python (higher numbers are rare, low numbers are common) random weighted chance

Tags: python, random, statistics

I'm looking to create a random function where 100 is the rarest number while 1 is the most common. It should be a linear distribution so for example the function returning 100 is the lowest chance, then 99 is the second lowest, then 98 is the third lowest and so forth. I've tried this code below:

```
def getPercentContent():
    minPercent = 5
    maxPercent = 102 # this will return 101 as highest number
    power = 1.5 # higher number, more concentration to lower numbers
    num = math.floor(minPercent+(maxPercent-minPercent)*random.random()**power)
    return str(num)
```

This does return a lot more low numbers through 1- 10, but after that, since its an exponential function, numbers 10-100 have a very similar count.

Is there any way to create a linear distribution like below: [image: Linear distribution of numbers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the distribution you're looking for, simply generate two numbers in the range and take their minimum. Here is an example:

```
min(random.randint(minPercent,maxPercent-1),
        random.randint(minPercent,maxPercent-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return an inverse of whatever number you're inputting and then normalise all values by the sum of all frequencies to get percentages:

```
def frequency(start: int = 0, end: int = 100):
    freq = [1/n for n in range(start, stop)]
    perc = [k/sum(freq) for k in freq]
    return perc
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is a [triangular distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution) with its mode (most frequently occurring value) equal to the min. These are built-in as a continuous distribution in the [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#real-valued-distributions) module or (if you want a lot of them fast) in [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.triangular.html). If you want integer outcomes from 1 to 100, inclusive, generate with `min = mode = 0` and `max = 100`, take the floor, and add 1 to the result.

The following code generates and plots a million triangular values in half a second on my laptop:

```python
from numpy.random import default_rng
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = default_rng()
data = rng.triangular(0, 0, 100, size = 1000000).astype(int) + 1

h = plt.hist(data, bins=100, density=True)
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image: Histogram of triangular values]